# Which one is correct: "PhD studies" or "PhD study"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am always confused when it comes to talking about my studies.
Could someone tell me which one is correct:

> I received financial support during my PhD **studies**.

or

> I received financial support during my PhD **study**.

It becomes even more confusing when it comes to Master's!
So, how about

> **Master's studies** vs. **Masters studies** vs. **Master's study** vs. **Master study**

Is that wrong to say

> I received financial support during my PhD **program**.

Comment: It's studies, both for PhD and master's.  Master's is capitalized only when talking about a specific degree, and then the *'s* is (often) dropped.  ex: "As a result of my master's studies I earned a Master of Science in chemistry."

Answer (score 1):

As Jason noted in his comment, the correct phrases are **PhD studies** and **master's studies**.